# Can I dual boot Linux and Windows 7 but use the Windows bootloader instead of GRUB?

Tags: windows-7, linux, grub, bootloader, multi-boot

Is it possible to have the Windows bootloader point to Windows 7 and a Linux partition instead of using GRUB to point to Windows 7 and Linux?

Any links to tutorials, guides, or how-tos would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the easiest way is to use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to manage the Windows boot manager.

[Here](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Linux) is a quick how-to, Windows 7 is basically the same as Vista.

Answer (score 0):

- In step 7 of install, go to advanced, and install grub in the /boot folder.
- Go here for a good article on [Installing GRUB and Making Ubuntu Bootable Using the Windows Bootloader](http://oreilly.com/linux/archive/dual-boot-laptop.html?page=3)
- If you are dual booting with Vista/Win7, download the program [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) (in Windows), and use it to make an entry for Ubuntu in Vista's bootloader.

Comment: CT didn't specify Ubuntu, and even if he did, according to the [EasyBCD pages](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu) the "advanced" bit doesn't work with the current version of Ubuntu. Your second point is about Windows XP, CT specified Windows 7 in the question.