# Uninstalling Kali Linux 2.0 from dual boot

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, grub, kali-linux

I recently installed `Kali Linux 2.0` along with genuine `Windows 7 Home Basic`.
But now I want to remove `Kali`, I thought to remove it by just formatting the partition in which `Kali` is installed, but the problem is about the `Grub loader`. How do I remove it?

I have `Windows OS` in `C:` and `Kali Linux` in `D:`.

I want a `safe` and a `genuine` way to remove `Kali` from my system.
(**Any other way than booting through CD/flash drive**)

Comment: Will that work for genuine windows too?

Comment: I followed the link, but it gets me to the payment section.
Isn't there any other way

Comment: you need to restore the windows bootloader.  easiest from a windows recovery cd/usb.  lots of similar questions: https://superuser.com/questions/188156/how-to-uninstall-grub-and-get-windows-7-bootloader-back http://askubuntu.com/questions/5748/how-to-restore-windows-7-mbr-without-a-cd