# Triple boot 3 OS's on 3 separate SSD's

Tags: windows-7, windows-8.1, ssd, multi-boot, bootloader

I am attempting to set up a system with 3 separate OS's (Windows 7, 8.1, and 10 TP) all on three separate SSD's. I can currently boot into each one if I use a boot override via the UEFI BIOS on my MoBo but for ease (and for my wife) I am hoping to be able to choose my OS using a bootloader option.

If my wife wants to use Win8 I don't want her having to spam F2 when booting and having to know the name of the drive in the bios to select it.

I have tried to use EasyBCD to manually add the other OS's into the boot loader via their drive letters but to no avail. It will show the options on the bootloader but all but the primary OS will give me a failur message (I have tried from both Win7 and 8.1). I am assuming this is because the BIOS requires me to boot from the "Windows Boot Manager" and will not allow booting by choosing the drive directly. I have also tried using the "bootrec /rebuildbcd" command in recovery mode of both Win7 and 8.1 to manually rebuild the bootloader but it will only see two of the three OS's and fails with a "Could not find specified file" message anyway.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Is there any way to install a different bootloader such as GRUB in a Windows only environment?

If I were to re-partition one of the OS disks and install Ubuntu on it could I set up a proper bootloader that way?

Update 1: After a little more research I realized that I am using a UEFI system so easyBCD will not do any good. Does anyone know of a way to get UEFI OS's to show up in a boot menu?

Comment: Your queston about Grub is answered [here](http://superuser.com/questions/187476/can-i-dual-boot-linux-and-windows-7-but-use-the-windows-bootloader-instead-of-gr?rq=1)

Comment: Please try to format your question next time, as I have just done for you. Paragraphs make things easier to read!

Comment: Most BIOS programs have and option to boot to a boot menu so you wouldn't have to spam F2. Aside from that, while I don't have any direct experience, it occurs to me that a 4th drive like a livecd (usb) with the bootloader on *that* may be useful..

Comment: You were on the right track with EasyBCD. Maybe you did not do it correctly. Here are the instructions ==> https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/bcd-based/

Comment: Install each OS on each drive while the others are disconnected, when all three are installed connect all of them then modify the bootloader using Easy BCD.